# Match JS string to PHP string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I would like to "export" a JS string to a PHP processing script and match them. When they match, i would like to go through a simple validation process and if the validation is successful, send off an email.

To put this in perspective, here is what my code looks like so far:

I have about 40 divs each represnting an item. The below html is an example of just one

**HTML**

```
<div class="Post odd postStyles">
    <input class="cheap" data-mail="email@sample.com" name="option" type="radio">
    <article>
        <h6 class="casinoHeading">Grosvenor Casino Birmingham</h6>
        <p class="">84 Hill Street, Birmingham, B5 4AH</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

As you can see, i am using  html5 data attributes for the string i want to use.

I then retrieve this string using the Jquery data() function.

Please see below:

```
$("input").click(function(){
    var mail = $(this).data();
    console.log(mail);
})
```

And this is the bit in which i get lost, unfortunately. I would like to be able to pass the variable mail to a php script which then runs a loop and finds the correct string. 
Runs through some simple validation and then sends off an email.

Here is the PHP script I've written:

```
<?php

    $emails = array(
        "email@sample.com", 
        "email@sample1.com", 
        "email@sample2.com", 
    );

    foreach($emails as $val) {
        print $val;
    }

    if(isset($_POST ['Name'], $_POST ['Telephone'], $_POST ['Position'], $_POST['Email'], $_POST ['Noparty'], $_POST ['Message'], $_POST ['Adress'], $_POST ['PostCode'], 
    $_POST ['Date'], $_POST ['Time'])) {
        var errors = array();
        $name = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['Name'])));
        $telephone = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['Telephone'])));
        $email = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['Email'])));
        $position = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['Position'])));
        $noparty = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['Noparty'])));
        $message = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Message'])));
        $address = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Adress'])));
        $postcode = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['PostCode'])));
        $date = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Date'])));
        $time = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Time'])));

        if(empty($name) || empty($telephone) || empty($email) || empty($position) || empty($noparty) || empty($message) || empty($address) || empty($postcode) || empty($date)
        empty($time)){
            $errors [] = "<span class='error'>Please fill in the required fields!</span>";
        }else{
            if(strlen($name)<=2 || strlen($name)>25){
                $errors [] = "<span class='error'>Sorry, username should be between 2 and 25 Charachters</span>";
            }
        }
        //If all runs through sucessfully - send email
    } 
?>
```

Essentially i want to be able to send that variable to PHP(maybe with an AJAX request), check it and then run some validation with it.

Can anyone help out?

Much appreciated,

Antonio

Comment: So you want to learn how to make an Ajax request? `->` http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: Check jquery ajax functions, JQuery post, for example: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: I know how to make an AJAX request. I dont, however, know how to structure it in order to send a JS variable and then refer to that variable in PHP. That is the essence of this question.

Comment: You are not sending "variables". You are sending data. You an either make a POST or GET request. The data are just characters, text. You just pass the data as argument to jQuery function you use. See http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/ for examples and information.

Comment: @Felix Kling - That cleared it up for me. I seemed to have the mechanics of it a bit confused. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! These things can be confusing at first. A basic but solid understanding of how HTTP works certainly helps. Anyways, have a look at the examples and maybe implement a simple demo which just sends one value and receives a simple response. Then you can make it work for the whole form. jQuery even provides helper methods to collect the form data, such as http://api.jquery.com/serialize/. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I truly don't understand your point.You can use $.post to send a form and then return JSON by PHP with errors or status OK.

You can grab attributes this way:

```
var mail;
$("input").click(function(){
   mail = $(this).val();
   if(!mail)
        mail = $(this).attr("data-mail"); 
});
$("#submit-button").on("click", function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post({});
});
```

You should do this with traditional way: html form, hidden inputs and simple submit button.

Comment: Ajaxing a form is not a stupid way. It's a method many sites use. Why repost a page, when you just need to send data. Also, the OP has no form in their code. You can't assume they wanted to use the "traditional" way as you call it...-1

Comment: Ok, so use $.post to send a form :)

Comment: AJAXING the form is required for the project im working on, im afraid. I also need to be able to pass the client side info to a server, validate it and then submit the form. Hence, the PHP posted.